# Is it possible to lower the strength of a Tier 3 base without destroying it?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

I'm currently attempting to siege a Tier 3 Mining Base that has 6 different blueprints that I want, and I don't want to pay for them.

As I'm on veteran, it's proving to be very hard work at my current level and with the ships I have available.

Two side missions (specifically [Poke an Eye Out](http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Poke_an_Eye_Out) and [Take Out the Take-Out](http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Take_Out_the_Take-Out)) allow you to lower the tier of one particular base (one for each mission).

After at least 30 side missions, I'm still yet to see either of these options come up in this system, while I've seen them quite a few times in other systems that don't contain Tier 3 bases.

Is it possible for either of these missions to appear if the related faction (the one that will lose a level) is at level 3?

Comment: I haven't noticed them being related. I'm not sure, though. Have you tried jumping out of the system and in again?

Comment: @ver Many, many times.

Comment: pretty sure those two side missions are the only way to lower the level of a base, but I don't remember if I've ever seen one in a tier 3 system either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the below two screenshots, it is entirely possible to find either of these two missions in a tier 3 system, no matter if only one of the bases is tier 3, or if both bases are tier 3.

It's just fairly uncommon.

[image]
[image]